# Problem installing Cloud9 from GitHub: support/node-builds-v4/node-linux64: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node.js, cloud9-ide

I am getting when I try to run

```
jiewmeng@klifmedia:~/cloud9$ sudo bin/cloud9.sh
[sudo] password for jiewmeng: 
--------------------------- Please wait, initializing submodules for first launch ------------------------
Submodule 'support/ace' (http://github.com/ajaxorg/ace.git) registered for path 'support/ace'
... ...
Resolving deltas: 100% (1419/1419), done.
Submodule path 'support/socket.io': checked out 'ee4c3bba5120d11489dc98da75082a2c65eac9e1'
--------------------------- Submodules installed ------------------------
Linux 64 bit
bin/cloud9.sh: 39: support/node-builds-v4/node-linux64: Permission denied
```

Whats wrong. How can I then install cloud9?

**UPDATE 1**

Reading downwards into the instructions, "Startup errors: Binaries and node.js", see that maybe I need to install o3 cos I'm on x64. I tried

```
jiewmeng@klifmedia:~$ git clone http://github.com/ajaxorg/o3
Cloning into o3...
...
jiewmeng@klifmedia:~$ cd o3
jiewmeng@klifmedia:~/o3$ ./tools/node_modules_build 
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local 
'configure' finished successfully (0.824s)
...
14:13:16 runner system command -> ['/usr/bin/g++', 'default/hosts/node-o3/sh_node_1.o', 'default/hosts/node-o3/sh_node_libs_1.o', '-o', '/home/jiewmeng/o3/build/default/o3.node', '-shared', '-L/usr/local/lib', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-lxml2']
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/jiewmeng/o3/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx_link sh_node_1.o,sh_node_libs_1.o -> o3.node}
  File "/usr/local/bin/node-waf", line 16, in <module>
    Scripting.prepare(t, os.getcwd(), VERSION, wafdir)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 147, in prepare
    error(str(e))
```

**UPDATE 2**

I solved the problem in Update 1 by installing `libxml2-dev`

```
jiewmeng@klifmedia:~/o3$ ./tools/node_modules_build 
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local 
'configure' finished successfully (0.374s)
...
'build' finished successfully (1m46.076s)      
jiewmeng@klifmedia:~/o3$ sudo cp build/default/o3.node ~/cloud9/support/jsdav/support/node-o3-xml-v4/lib/o3-xml/
```

then ... back to the same error ...

```
jiewmeng@klifmedia:~$ cd cloud9/
jiewmeng@klifmedia:~/cloud9$ bin/cloud9.sh
Linux 64 bit
bin/cloud9.sh: 39: support/node-builds-v4/node-linux64: Permission denied
```

Comment: You should go to the support forum/mailing list/IRC channel for Cloud9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried chmod +x support/node-builds-v4/node-linux64?

Answer (score 1):

Set the value for the variable NODE_PATH in terminal as follows:

```
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"
```

Answer (score 0):

I received a information that this permission issue should be already fixed. Please try again.